# preterite or imperfect estar?

Tags: gramática

Una cosa ha cambiado desde que **estuvimos** en el bosque.
 Es correcto?

En Ingles...
Im making a list of sample scentences using several of the key verbs, and in all the tenses and moods.  The Spanishdict.com seems to conflict with google translate.  Google translate wants the above example to use the imperfect for estar.  eg.  (en español) Una cosa ha cambiado desde que **estábamos** en el bosque.

Which one is right?

Esta confuso!  En mi opinión creo que Spanishdict.com tiene razón porque "were in the woods" ya está acabado.

Comment: Please fix your spelling and punctuation. They are both right. **It depends on what you want to say**. You cannot use Google translate to see what is good in Spanish. You need to find an educated native speaker of Spanish. They both mean "were" in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que se usa "ha cambiado", la opción correcta es "desde que estuvimos en el bosque".

Comment: ¿Y si digo "Muchas cosas han cambiado desde que vivíamos en el barrio"? Parece válido. ¿Porqué "estuvimos en el bosque"? Ambas tienen "ha/n cambiado". Poco razonada la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos cuestiones que veo aquí. Una gramatical y otra de significado.

La frase
"Una cosa ha cambiado desde que estuvimos en el bosque."

es correcta porque al usar el pretérito perfecto simple "estuvimos"  te estás refiriendo a una situación en un momento puntual del pasado que terminó. Por eso, usar el pretérito perfecto ("ha cambiado") es adecuado. Ambas formas verbales
tienen aspecto perfectivo.

[1] Uso la nomenclatura de https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempos_verbales_en_espa%C3%B1ol

La frase del comentario

"Muchas cosas han cambiado desde que vivíamos en el barrio"

también es correcto. Pero el usar el imperfecto
"vivíamos en el barrio" denota una acción habitual en el pasado. Y "han cambiado" en cambio dice que las cosas referidas ya han terminado de cambiar [en un momento del pasado, no pr (sino diría ""Muchas cosas están cambiado desde que vivíamos en el barrio")